# Create for each user image gallery php

Tags: php

I'm trying to create for each user his own gallery where he can upload images.

table    ***images*** :

> CREATE TABLE `images` (  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
> `file_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
> `uploaded_on` datetime NOT NULL,  `status` enum('1','0') COLLATE
> utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',  `iduser` int(11),  PRIMARY KEY
> (`id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

and a table ***tbl_users*** with primary key **id**
where

> iduser

is a foreign key from table ***tbl_users***

here's **upload.php**:

```
<?php 
// Include the database configuration file 
include_once 'dbConfig.php'; 
     
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
    // File upload configuration 
    $targetDir = "uploads/"; 
    $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif'); 
     
    $statusMsg = $errorMsg = $insertValuesSQL = $errorUpload = $errorUploadType = ''; 
    $fileNames = array_filter($_FILES['files']['name']); 
    if(!empty($fileNames)){ 
        foreach($_FILES['files']['name'] as $key=>$val){ 
            // File upload path 
            $fileName = basename($_FILES['files']['name'][$key]); 
            $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName; 
             
            // Check whether file type is valid 
            $fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
            if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){ 

                // Upload file to server 
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key], $targetFilePath)){ 
                    // Image db insert sql 
                    $insertValuesSQL .= "('".$fileName."', NOW()),"; 
                }else{ 
                    $errorUpload .= $_FILES['files']['name'][$key].' | '; 
                } 
            }else{ 
                $errorUploadType .= $_FILES['files']['name'][$key].' | '; 
            } 
        } 
         
        // Error message 
        $errorUpload = !empty($errorUpload)?'Upload Error: '.trim($errorUpload, ' | '):''; 
        $errorUploadType = !empty($errorUploadType)?'File Type Error: '.trim($errorUploadType, ' | '):''; 
        $errorMsg = !empty($errorUpload)?'<br/>'.$errorUpload.'<br/>'.$errorUploadType:'<br/>'.$errorUploadType; 
         
        if(!empty($insertValuesSQL)){ 
            $insertValuesSQL = trim($insertValuesSQL, ','); 
            // Insert image file name into database 
            $insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO images (file_name, uploaded_on) VALUES $insertValuesSQL"); 
            if($insert){ 
                $statusMsg = "Files are uploaded successfully.".$errorMsg; 
            }else{ 
                $statusMsg = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file."; 
            } 
        }else{ 
            $statusMsg = "Upload failed! ".$errorMsg; 
        } 
    }else{ 
        $statusMsg = 'Please select a file to upload.'; 
    } 
} 
 
?>
```

*index.html:*

```
<?php
// Include the database configuration file
include_once 'upload.php';
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            upload
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Select Image Files to Upload:
            <input   type="file" name="files[]" multiple >
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="UPLOAD">
        </form>
        <?php
// Get images from the database
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY id DESC");

if($query->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
        $imageURL = 'uploads/'.$row["file_name"];
?>
    <img class="image" src="<?php echo $imageURL; ?>" alt="" />
<?php }
}else{ ?>
    <p>No image(s) found...</p>
<?php } ?> 
    </body>
</html>
```